# Creating a new file or directory in LAMP?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

How do I create a directory in the LAMP root folder (var/www) using the terminal and LAMP. I'm just getting to grips at using Linux/Ubuntu and I've just setup LAMP so I'm still not to sure on how I can do this.

Once I've setup the directory how can I create sub-folders (images, css, includes, etc) within that folder/directory. Then create a .php, .css and maybe .js files and save them into the root directory and sub-folders?

Thanks

Will

Comment: This is not a php, lamp or css question. Retagging.

Comment: mkdir is the linux function you want

Comment: @Dragon put that as the answer and I'll +1 it.

Answer (score 2):

`mkdir` is the linux function you want

Example:

```
mkdir DIR_NAME
```

http://www.oreillynet.com/linux/cmd/cmd.csp?path=m/mkdir

reading up on the basics of linux would be a good idea

Comment: So how would I type that in Terminal?

Comment: it will create the directory under what ever directory you are currently in. to change directory use `cd`

Comment: So - mkdir websitename cd var/www ?

cd stands for change directory right?

Comment: try it and see, then you will know. you can use  `rmdir` (remove directory) if you make a mistake

Answer (score 1):

Steps per line:

1. Create a directory called "mysite" under /var/www: "mkdir /var/www/mysite"
2. Change working directory to /var/www/mysite: "cd /var/www/mysite"
3. Open editor called "vile" and start with a new document called "index.php": "vi index.php"

For help with the vile editor, http://linux.die.net/man/1/vi

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a textual file, you could use an editor like e.g. `emacs`